# Permission denied from opening directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, ls, cd-command

I have always wondered how you stop another user from entering a directory. I am in a local installation of GitLab and I see that in my `git` directory I have a `repositories` directory. If I try to `ls` or `cd` into it, it says:

```
me@my:/home/git$ ls repositories/
ls: cannot open directory 'repositories/': Permission denied
me@my:/home/git$ cd repositories/
bash: cd: repositories/: Permission denied
```

If I `ls` the parent directory I see it doesn't belong to me. But I don't see anything that stops me from going in.

```
 drwxrws---  3 git  git  4096 Jul  5 00:47 repositories
```

How is it stopping me from entering or exploring this directory?

I am not interested in getting into this directory. I am more interested in how they stopped me from getting into it and how I can stop others from getting into directories in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Main Idea

To stop anyone apart from you having access to a folder, all you have to do is make sure that the last 6 characters in a `ls -l` are dashes. For example: `drwx------`

## Instructions for terminal

`drwx------` will give you full read, write and execute permissions, but only for your user. To set this you have to run `chmod 700 folder`, where `folder` is the folder you want to block.

## Instructions for GUI

In most file managers, you can right click on the folder, open up the preferences and give the owner read and write permission and set the group and others to no permissions. If your file manager doesn't work like this, post a comment with the name of your file manager so I can add specific instructions for that file manager.

Thanks @ravery for the GUI instructions

NOTE: I will add in pictures when I get a chance

Comment: So using `chmod` how would you set those on that directory's permissions?

Comment: If you use `chmod` you will be overwriting either the `git` user or the `git` group and that will probably stop GitLab from working. Using `usermod` is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of `chown`

Comment: Although using `chmod` will get rid of the SUID (`s`) and that might stuff up GitLab as well

Comment: I updated the question. I am interested in how they blocked me. I don't need access to that repositories directory. I want to know to block others like they blocked me in the future.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: if you are using a GUI file manager, right click on the file then properties, then permissions. Set group and others to denied; and owner to read write.

Comment: @ravery I'll add that in. Do you want me to mention you

Comment: if you want, it isn't necessary though